# Quick way to get closed form for this recurrence?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, recurrence-relations, closed-form

Is there supposed to be a fast way to compute recurrences like these?

$T(1) = 1$

$T(n) = 2T(n - 1) + n$

The solution is $T(n) = 2^{n+1} - n - 2$.

I can solve it with:

1. Generating functions.
2. Subtracting successive terms until it becomes a pure linear recurrence $T(n) = 4T(n-1) - 5T(n-2) + 2T(n-3)$ and then solving it using the powers-of-roots approach.
3. Repeated substitution, which gives a few simple closed-forms but one messy sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} 2^k k$ which to me is not easy to do quickly.

Each one of these approaches takes me several minutes to flesh out, but I feel like this is supposed to be one of those questions I should be able to answer in a few seconds and move on. What am I missing? Is there some quick trick to doing these recurrences?

Comment: Generating functions. Flexible, applicable most everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as in linear algebra, the general solution of a linear non-homogeneous equation is a particular solution + the general solution of the homogeneous equation.

The homogeneous equation $T(n) = 2 T(n-1)$ has the obvious solutions $c 2^n$.

For a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation $T(n) = 2 T(n-1) + n$, since the non-homogeneous term is a polynomial of degree $1$ it's  natural to look for a solution that is again a polynomial of degree $1$: try $a n + b$ and you see that $-n - 2$ fits the bill.

EDIT: What I mean is that substituting $T(n) = a n + b$ gives you 
$a n + b  = 2 (a (n-1) + b) + n$, which simplifies to $(a + 1) n + b - 2 a = 0$, and since this is true for all $n$ you must have $a+1 = 0$, $b-2a = 0$, i.e. $a=-1$ and $b = -2$.

So your general solution is $T(n) = c 2^n - n - 2$, and you plug in the initial condition $n = 1$ to see that $c = 2$.

Comment: "try $an+b$ and you see that $−n−2$ fits the bill" Can you elaborate on what you mean by this? I was with  you up until this part. How do you separate the homogeneous from the non-homogeneous correctly? They appear to be intertwined so I am unsure how to separate.

Comment: Do you have any recommended resources for solving non-homogeneous recurrences? I'd like to learn how to do them without needing to guess or eyeball anything; something systematic I can use until it becomes intuitive enough so I can eyeball them

Comment: It's just like constant-coefficient linear differential equations.  If the non-homogeneous term is a polynomial of degree $n$, and $1$ is not a solution of the homogeneous equation, try a polynomial of degree $n$.  If $x^0, \ldots, x^k$ are solutions of the homogeneous equation but $x^{k+1}$ is not, try $x^{k+1}$ times a polynomial of degree $n$.  If the homogeneous term is $c^n$ times a polynomial of degree $n$, where $c$ is a constant, do the same with $c^n$ times a polynomial... Trig functions can be expressed using complex exponentials.

Comment: I am not really sure I understand. Why does $1$ not have to be a solution of the homogeneous equation? What does that mean, technically?

Comment: Let's say your trial solution is a polynomial $a_d n^d + \ldots + a_0$ of degree $d$,  Ordinarily, when you put that in to the equation you get another polynomial of degree $d$, and you end up solving $d+1$ equations in $d+1$ unknowns for the coefficients $a_0,\ldots, a_d$, as I did with $d=1$ in the example.  But if the constant $1$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation, you get a polynomial of lower degree, and the coefficient of $1$ doesn't appear at all.

Comment: For example, consider $T(n) - T(n-1) = n^2+1$.  $T(n) = 1$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation $T(n) - T(n-1) = 0$, but $T(n) = n$ is not.  So your trial solution should be $T(n) = a_3 n^3 + a_2 n^2  + a_1 n$, which makes $T(n) - T(n-1) = 3 a_3 n^2 + (3 a_3 + 2 a_2) n + (a_3 + a_2 + a_1)$, So you want $3 a_3 = 1$, $3 a_3 + 2 a_2 = 0$, $a_3 + a_2 + a_1 = 1$.

Comment: I don't understand how $1$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation. You are putting all the homogeneous terms on the lefthand side, right? And then somehow you are checking if the righthand side equals $0$ when you try $1$ somewhere? If I do $T(n) - T(n-1)$ where $n=1$ I see $(n^2+1) - ((n-1)^2+1) = (1^2 + 1) - ((1-1)^2 +1) = 2 - 1 = 1$, not $0$?

Comment: In general I am very uncomfortable with the idea of "guessing" the solution, because what if the recurrence were much more complex (several homogeneous linear terms, a nasty looking non-homogeneous expression, for example)

Comment: $T(n) = 1$ satisfies $T(n-1) = 1$, and therefore $T(n) - T(n-1) = 0$.  $n^2+1$ is not the solution, it's the inhomogeneous term of the problem.

Comment: How does $T(n) = 1$ satisfy $T(n-1) = 1$? I don't mean to be dense but I cannot understand most of what you are saying because I feel like I'm missing some fundamental step of your argument. It sounds like you're saying if $T(n) = 1$ then $T(n-k) = 1$ for any arbitrary $k$, but this sounds like you're arbitrarily redefining $T(n)$ to just be equal to $1$ as opposed to the recurrence?

Comment: I am self-studying all this material so it's possible I'm missing something as a result of not having a formal class in this subject.

Comment: When I write $T(n) = 1$, I mean $T$ is the constant function with value $1$.   So $T(anything) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Generating functions. Define $t(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} T(n) z^n$, shift indices to $T(n + 1) = 2 T(n) + n + 1$; by the recurrence backwards $T(0) = 0$, and you get directly:

$\begin{align}
  \frac{t(z) - T(0)}{z}
    &= 2 t(z) + \sum_{n \ge 0} (n + 1) z^n \\
    &= 2 t(z) + \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2} \\
  t(z)
    &= \frac{z}{1 - 4 z + 5 z^2 - 2 z^3} \\
    &= \frac{2}{1 - 2 z} - \frac{1}{1 - z} - \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2}
\end{align}$

You can read off the terms from the partial fraction expansion:

$\begin{align}
   T(n)
     &= 2 \cdot 2^n - 1 - (n + 1) \\
     &= 2^{n + 1} - n - 2
\end{align}$

Comment: This was one of my approaches too but I had a big slowdown once I encountered the cubic equation. I didn't know how to factor it quickly.

Comment: That's what computer algebra is for..

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the computer algebra? I can use computers to solve the original recurrence if I wanted to, but I still want to learn to do these by hand, too.

Comment: @ArukaJ one of the factors of the denominator is clear from the left hand side (don't multiply out, like maxima does)

Answer (score 1):

Let me make the problem slightly more complex with, for example, $$T_n=a \, T_{n-1}+b+c n+d n^2$$ ($a,b,c,d$ being given); set $$T_n=U_n+\alpha +\beta  n+\gamma  n^2$$ Now, replace in the original expression
$$U_n+\alpha+\beta  n +\gamma  n^2=a\left(U_{n-1}+\alpha +\beta  (n-1)+\gamma  (n-1)^2\right)+b+c n+d n^2$$ that is to say $$U_n-aU_{n-1}=a\left(\alpha +\beta  (n-1)+\gamma  (n-1)^2\right)+b+c n+d n^2-(\alpha+\beta  n +\gamma  n^2)$$ Expanding the rhs and grouping for a given power of $n$ then gives
$$(a \alpha -a \beta +a \gamma -\alpha +b)+n (a \beta -2 a \gamma -\beta +c)+n^2 (a
   \gamma -\gamma +d)$$ Say that, for any $n$, this expression is equal to $0$. This gives three linear equations for three unknowns $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$; these are easy to solve and you then finish with the simplest reccurence equation $$U_n=a\,U_{n-1}$$ Then, back to $T_n$.

For sure, you can generalized the problem to any recurrence of the form $$T_n=a \, T_{n-1}+\sum_{i=0}^k c_in^i$$

Answer (score 0):

Solve the homogeneous equation by removing any non-functional terms. In this case, simply remove the n.

Solve the specific solution by guessing. In this case, it's not difficult. Try plugging in Ax + b into the functional equation, and see if you can solve for the coefficients.

Then, add both solutions together for the general solution.